# xcode hangs on breakpoints

Tags: iphone

I have sample application it works fine. When i set breakpoint in my project it didn't step over from breakpoint, the application hangs with that break point its really hard to find what the problem is. With out break points its work fine.

I want to test some variables with breakpoints in simulator 4.0 debug can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Have you restarted Xcode / your computer lately?

Comment: happening to me and other too I'm sure. no idea how to fix it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue until I upgraded to the latest XCode 4.5. Its seems to have solved the XCode - Not Responding issues and Crash. Hope this will help.